# Pegar uma parte específica de uma string utilizando metodo split ANDROID

Tags: java, android, string

Fiz um codigo para exibição de processos no android mas ao imprimir em um text view, ele imprime o PID, nome do processo, uso de cpu memoria etc.  a exibição fica dessa maneira

```
958  2   0% S    22 577164K  42624K  bg u0_a63   com.snaptube.premium
```

eu gostaria de imprimir somente "com.snaptube.premium"

tentei utilizar o metodo split mas não obtive exito

meu código para exibição dos processos esta assim

```
  p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command); // uso para utilizar comandos do linux
  p.waitFor();
  String line = ""; // string que contem a linha com as informações do processo
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new  InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));                      
  BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);            

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
                output.append(line + "\n"); // impressao dos processos no textview
```

criei uma variavel String [] auxiliar e atribui a ela o line.lengh() - 1 e usei line.split("") para separar a string por espaço em branco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é necessário a função `split`.
Se é a ultima parte do texto é mais simples recorrer aos métodos [substring](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29) e [lastIndexOf](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28java.lang.String%29) da classe [String](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html)

```
String parteFinal = texto.substring(texto.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1)
```

O método [substring(int start)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29) retorna a parte da string a começar no índice passado ao parâmetro até ao fim da mesma.

Para saber qual é o índice a passar a [substring()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29) usamos o método [lastIndexOf(String string)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28java.lang.String%29) que retorna o índice da ultima ocorrência da string passada como parâmetro.

```
                                                 _substring(start+1)_
                                                 |                  |
958  2   0% S    22 577164K  42624K  bg u0_a63   com.snaptube.premium
                                                ^
                                                |
                                              start = texto.lastIndexOf(" ")
```

Comment: deu certo

Muito obrigado

Poderia me explicar o funcionamento para eu entender°? Conhecia o substring mas nao o lastofIndex

E por que nao era necessario o slipt?

Comment: Editei a resposta com uma pequena explicação.

Comment: entendi agora 
na saida do texto, estão saindo 3 strings que eu nao gostaria que saisse, uma delas é o uso de cpu e um PID, (só sai uma vez) mas ficam variando

10-16 17:12:06.460 3092-3092/? I/System.out: 0%
10-16 17:12:06.460 3092-3092/? I/System.out: 1170
10-16 17:12:06.460 3092-3092/? I/System.out: Name

de resto esta funcionando. sabe como eu poderia ignorar essas 3 strings que saem? e começar a imprimir a partir da 4º string que é onde começam os processos?

Comment: O correcto é você criar uma nova pergunta. Convido-o a que veja como o site funciona na [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) e [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) a forma de proceder quando uma resposta te foi útil.